# Google Map Dev Watermark can't get rid of it

Tags: api, google-maps

I have a google map embedded with a wordpress plugin. I am getting the developer wordmark overlay on my map even though I have attached it to a billing account. I have the exact same setup on our Canadian site but it will not work on the USA site. Any ideas? I am using a different API key. Could I use the same one on both sites?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some how I had multiple maps loading, once I found that and erased the other instances the watermark has been removed.